# How to alter Event Dropdown values from Register Participant or New Event Registration Page?

Tags: civievent

On Register Particpant Page, I see list of all Events under Event dropdown
As per the requirement, I am using Recurring Entity to have repeat 
events,so I need to hide repeat events and display only parent events
How can we alter the results in the Event dropdown 
[image]

The Event dropdown has this form structure (from hook_buildForm)
When I add a condition and try to print variables inside it on New Participant Registration it does not show up.(probably since its entering )

```
 $apiRequest['entity'] == 'event'

/**
 * Implements hook_civicrm_apiWrappers
 */
function custom_changes_civicrm_apiWrappers(&$wrappers, $apiRequest) {

  if ($apiRequest['entity'] == 'event' ) {
    print_r('<pre>');
    print_r($apiRequest);
    print_r($wrappers);
    die('ed'); 
 }
}
```

[image]

On adding the code answered below

```
if ('CRM_Event_Form_Participant' == $formName) {
    $elementIndex = $form->_elementIndex['event_id'];
    $element = & $form->_elements[$elementIndex];
    $dataApiParams = json_decode($element->_attributes['data-api-params'], TRUE);
    $dataApiParams['params'] = ['parent_event_id' => ['IS NULL' => 1]];
    $element->_attributes['data-api-params'] = json_encode($dataApiParams);   }
```

I get an error (when I comment I don't get the error).

> Error: Call to undefined method stdClass::getName() in
>   HTML_QuickForm->accept() (line 1686 of
>   csites\all\modules\civicrm\packages\HTML\QuickForm.php).

To fix that I actually went to QuickForm.php and added an if condition as seen below

```
if(method_exists($element,'getName')
```

Is that a correct method and if not , how can I debug that further based on the error log.

```
 function accept(&$renderer)
    {
        $renderer->startForm($this);
        foreach (array_keys($this->_elements) as $key) {
            $element =& $this->_elements[$key];
            if (method_exists($element,'getName')){
            $elementName = $element->getName();
            $required    = ($this->isElementRequired($elementName) && !$element->isFrozen());
            $error       = $this->getElementError($elementName);
            $element->accept($renderer, $required, $error);
            }
        }
        $renderer->finishForm($this);
    } // end func accept
```

Comment: If you need to list only the parent event - then you need some development to achieve the same

Answer (score 3):

The event field on participant form uses event api to retrieve events. You can easily alter the list by implementing [hook_civicrm_apiWrappers](https://docs.civicrm.org/dev/en/latest/hooks/hook_civicrm_apiWrappers/) hook by adding additional parameter to exclude recurring event in $params of api probably `'parent_event_id' => ['IS NULL' => 1]`.

Or using buildform hook try adding parent_event_id condition in data-api-params of the field(element).

```
if ('CRM_Event_Form_Participant' == $formName) {
    $elementIndex = CRM_Utils_Array::value('event_id', $form->_elementIndex);
    if (empty($elementIndex)) {
      return;
    }
    $element = & $form->_elements[$elementIndex];
    $dataApiParams = json_decode($element->_attributes['data-api-params'], TRUE);
    $dataApiParams['params'] = ['parent_event_id' => ['IS NULL' => 1]];
    $element->_attributes['data-api-params'] = json_encode($dataApiParams);
  }
```

Cheers

Pradeep

Comment: Hi @pradeep, can you provide an example, I see the following source code in the Event Dropdown element,kindly check the updated answer.

Comment: I said to use api wrapper hook to add additional condition, the documentation is straight forward,i think you will understand if you use it

Comment: Hi @Pradeep, yes I am trying ,let me update the question on what I tried.

Comment: Just updated my answer on how you can use buildform

Comment: Really sorry, but I have never added condition in data-api-params, hence was looking for an example on how i can add it in hook_buildForm()

Comment: Updated my answer to include the snippet, but i havent tested it. But it should be something like that

Comment: Thanks , i will test it, you are very quick.

Comment: Let us know how it went

Comment: Hi @Pradeep, yes I finally created an event_type_id for child events because parent_event_id was not able to distinguish between parent(first event) and child event (subsequent event) as parent_event_id was present for both parent and child event, hence I added condition in the params above as ['params']['event_type_id']['!='] = 8(where 8 is an event_type id named Repeat for child event) repeat event type is added hook_civicrm_post when RecurringEntity is created and parent_id != entity_id,  if you feel it can improved, let me know, I will improve on it.will post my answer in detail later

Comment: Hi @Pradeep,  the above code gives an error in the console 500 error, and which results in payment blocked not displayed when its a paid event.

Comment: The intension was to provide a way on how you can do that rather exact working solution. You will need to debug $form why its failing in certain case and then add condition based on it.

Comment: Hi @pradeep,I completely agree with your point, I will send you where the error ,maybe its some core issue.

Comment: Hi Pradeep, I have updated my question,kindly have a re look at it

Comment: Updated the code snippet with required validation!

Comment: Hi Pradeep, thanks a lot you have been helping in my every civicrm problems !!